# Netty throws IOException:A connection with a remote socket was reset by that socket

Tags: sockets, netty, reset, ioexception

I'm using Netty3.5.9(jdk1.6.43) for my socket connections,most of the time ,it works well,but sometimes it shows:

java.io.IOException:A connection with a remote socket was reset by that socket

```
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.read0(Native Method)

at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:33)

at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:234)

at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:201)

at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:236)

at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:321)

at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.processSelectedKeys(NioWorker.java:280)

at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:200)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:896)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:735)
```

2013-7-2 8:54:18 org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler null
WARNING: EXCEPTION, please implement
 cfca.xfraud.collector.system.sockettype.netty.NettyAnalyzerHandler.exceptionCaught() for proper handling.

which my exceptionCaught() method is:

public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e) throws Exception {

```
    log.error("", e.getCause());
    super.exceptionCaught(ctx, e);

}
```

Though the IOException shows sometimes,but the whole application seems has no any bad influence and stills works well,so what's the real problem,and what should I change the code to prevent the exception.

Comment: Does it *really* say "java.io.IOException:A connection with a remote socket was reset by that socket"? or does it say "connection reset by peer"?

Comment: it really says "java.io.IOException:A connection with a remote socket was reset by that socket",I am quite sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing to be concerned about ... It means that the remote peer closed the connection  and netty detect it when the read is done. So you are safe to ignore the exception.

Comment: ok,thank you so much,but how can I prevent writing this exception log to log files. after all,It makes me feel uncomfortable to see this excepiton words...

Comment: override exceptionCaught(...) and swallow them ?